# Zybooks Java odd result

Tags: java, methods

I am currently in my first year doing Java and have gotten to my final, we do everything through Zybooks which has been fine up until now. whenever i am submitting the program it spits back a result with a 4 sided yellow square with a question mark in it,

**the code is here:**

```
private void updateDisplay() 
  {

   System.out.println("=========================");
   System.out.println("Messages: " + message);
   System.out.print("Letters Guessed: ");
   for(int i=0; i <lettersGuessed.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(lettersGuessed[i] + ", ");
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Bad Guesses: " + numBadGuesses);
   System.out.print("Puzzle: ");
   for(int i=0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(puzzle[i] + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("=========================");
   if(gameStatus == Status.WIN) {
   }
   else if(gameStatus == Status.LOSE) {
   }
   }
    public void processGuess(String rawInput) {
   message = "";
   if(isSingleLetter(rawInput)) {
       char guess = rawInput.charAt(0);
       if(isCharInArray(guess, lettersGuessed)) {
           message = "That letter has already been guessed.";
       }
       else {
           lettersGuessed[numGuesses] = guess;
           numGuesses++;
           if(isCharInArray(guess, wordToGuess.toCharArray())) {
               updatePuzzle(wordToGuess, guess, puzzle);
               if(doesArrayMatchString(puzzle, wordToGuess)) {
                   gameStatus = Status.WIN;
                   message = "You win! Game over.";

               }
           }
           else {
               numBadGuesses++;
               if(numBadGuesses == MAX_NUM_BAD_GUESSES) {
                   gameStatus = Status.LOSE;
                   message = "You lose! Game over.";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   else {
       message = "Guess must be a single letter.";
   }
  }
```

hopefully this will clear the things up for an answer, if not i could always just post screenshots of the lines of code

[image: this is a picture of the result i am getting (the yellow is the part that needs to be taken out)]

Comment: Where is the declaration of `lettersGuessed`, and what kinds of values are you assigning to its elements?

Comment: would it be best to just post the entire code? i just didn't want to cram close to 200 lines of code.

Comment: Just enough for people who want to help you to be able to reproduce the problem.  The problem is basically that `lettersGuessed` contains the wrong thing.  So if you don't show the code that populates `lettersGuessed`, nobody can really help you fix it.

Comment: Actually no, I think what's probably happening is that `lettersGuessed` is full of zeroes (uninitialised values, not the character `'0'`), and you're trying to print them all.  You should probably have a variable that tells you how many values you've actually inserted into `lettersGuessed`, instead of relying on `lettersGuessed.length`, since the latter only gives you the declared length of the array.

Comment: But without seeing your code, that's just an educated guess.

Comment: i just updated the original question, hopefully giving clarity on lettersGuessed and if not ill just go ahead and post the some screenshots if needed i also have this line that was already put into the code for me by my instructor and was told not to move or replace it.  // private char[] lettersGuessed = new char[26];    //

Comment: Yeah, I was right. Change `lettersGuessed.length` to `numGuesses` in the loop that prints them.

Comment: alright one last thing, this all fixed it, THANK YOU so much. so now it runs through like it should however right after that for loop is the print to print out the letter guessed then add a comma and a space, i need those except for on the last letter guessed i need it to drop the comma and space, how can i go about fixing this, i know its something easy but im brain numb because of this final. thanks if you can help.

Comment: Only print the comma if `i != numGuesses - 1`.